# Problema con particiones discos duros kali/windows dualboot

Tags: windows, kali-linux

Quería instalar el SO Kali y así lo hice, tengo dos discos duros uno 'C' y 'G', tengo windows instalado en el C e iba instalar Kali en el G.
Al usar el instalador decía que crearía una particion nueva en el disco para el SO, por lo tanto escogí el disco G para la instalación.
Kali se ha instalado y a creado la partición, pero en windows no aparece el disco duro G por ningún lado.

¿Como puedo hacer que vuelva a poder usar ese disco duro con windows? se puede?

No me gustaría tener un mismo disco duro que se use por los dos SO a la vez.
¿Podría crear una partición que solo pueda usar Kali y el resto para windows?

Comment: No aparece porque Windows NO puede leer particiones Linuxeras, si deseas que eso sea posible, necesitas instalar WSL (Windows Subsystem Linux) y hacer algunas configuraciones adicionales.

Comment: vale Gracias! 1